# Produce reference which reads "section/graph etc. X on page X"

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, varioref

I am new to LaTeX, this question is basic, but I have tried to solve it to no avail. I don't understand the LaTeX lingo too well, so I'd appreciate an answer a complete beginner will get. Thank you.

I want to produce an automatic reference which states (1) the object I am referring to (section, graph, etc.) and (2) the position in the document (if on the same page, "above"/"below", next page etc.). When I load both packages and use `\vref`, the procedure works if I copy the relevant sections of text/ code into a new Latex document and run it twice. It does not work in the original Latex document. Instead of producing "section 5 on the following page" it produces "?? on the following page".

The only significant difference between the two documents (that I can think of) is the preamble. Could this be the problem? If not, what then?

Dummy preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[american]{babel}  
\usepackage{varioref}  
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage{cleveref}  
\begin{document}
```

'Real' file

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\chapter{Manuel}

\section{Text Passage Summary and Irrelevant Information}

\subsection{Text Passages and their Usage}

\subsection{Eliminating Irrelevant Information: Descriptive and Speculative Text}

\section{The Object}

\subsection{Identifying the Object}

\subsection{Summarizing Relevant Information Concerning the Object}
\textbf{Both or either the object and/or its surrounding text may contain relevant information}, so that both must be looked at carefully. Information is relevant if it provides particular kinds of details about what the party wants to do. What kind of information is relevant will be described in \vref{sec:means}. 

\pagebreak

\section{Identifying Relevant Information} \label{sec:means}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you compile twice? That's necessary, since the cross-referencing information is known at the end of the first run, but not at the begin of it. Sometimes, three compilation runs are necessary

Comment: I am a bit ashamed, now I have and it's fine. I tried it in the actual document I am working in and it continues to produce the ??, however, and I compiled that millions of times.

Comment: Sometimes it's a typo for the label name, i.e. `\label{foo}` and `\ref{foO}` will cause a `??`, as well as `\ref{fo o}` would cause it, but `\ref{foo}` will work, as well as `\cref{foo}` etc.

Comment: Nope, the labels are identical. Thanks for your suggestions though.

Comment: Please post the minimal version of your document that has the issue, not just fragments

Comment: What happens if you remove the first `\usepackage{hyperref}` of the longer preamble?

Comment: Thanks for updating ... it think, it is the first `hyperref`  package loading.  It is too early, especially considering the fact that `tcolorbox` is loaded as well. Remove the first `\usepackage{hyperref}` please!

Comment: That was it actually! Thank you so much! I was sitting with this problem for 2 or 3 hours. If I want to avoid these package order kinds of problems in the future, is there somewhere I can read up on that? Would you say there may be other such problems in the preamble?

Comment: I compiled your new example (the long one) →`cleveref` complains about a missing format, most likely since the first `hyperref` comes too early and `tcolorbox` (having some `cleveref` code as well). Removing the first `hyperref` loading and recompiling twice →the correct reference appears

Comment: A general rule is to load  `hyperref` always at the end of the preamble; if needed (i.e. its usage is requested): `varioref` before `hyperref`, `cleveref` even after `hyperref`, since those  packages do 'massive' additions to the `\label`, and `\ref` macros and the counter system

Comment: Will keep that in mind, thank you! All the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct load order should be `varioref`, `hyperref`, `cleveref`

Interchanging the load order of `varioref` and `hyperref` in the following document will produce warnings and the references are wrong, since `varioref` hooks into the label system, as well as `hyperref` does, calling `varioref` later than `hyperref`, the linking and labelling and all achievement by `hyperref` is damaged.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

See \vref{foosection}

\chapter{Foo chapter}\label{foochapter}
\blindtext
\section{Foo section} \label{foosection}
\blindtext[5]



\end{document}
```